# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I dont get it. What is wrong with this query

```
While _drRemoteData.Read
    Dim _Query As String = "insert into SchedularTicketsData (RemoteDBID,key,Transno,DateEntered,DateUpdated) values (" & _dbrStores.Item("id") & "," & _drRemoteData("Key") & "," & _drRemoteData("TransNo") & ",NOW(),NOW())"
    _cmdExecute = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(_Query, _ConLMS)
    Try
        _cmdExecute.ExecuteNonQuery()
        WriteLog("Ticket number added " & _drRemoteData("TransNo"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("Ticket number not added " & _drRemoteData("TransNo"))
        WriteLog("Error message: " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End While
```

Debugger before execution is showing query

> "insert into SchedularTicketsData
>   (RemoteDBID,key,Transno,DateEntered,DateUpdated) values
>   (167,28570,28412,NOW(),NOW())"

Execution throw me an error :

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Screenshot

[image: Error showcase]

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: @LarsTech belived me or not i did added parameters here and tried but problem still persisted so i deleted them :)

Comment: Well, put them back.  I'm not your downvoter, but posting sql syntax without parameters usually attracts a lot of down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` is a [reserved word in ms-access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE). Put it in square brackets and it should work:

```
Dim _Query As String = "insert into SchedularTicketsData (RemoteDBID, [key], Transno,...
```

Comment: this  doesnt make problem when running as macro. But running from external application do make problem ;:)